# I need to slice one image into 50 different images automatically.

Tags: adobe-photoshop, slices

I have a big image that needs to be sliced into about 50 smaller images. I know there is a way to do it using 'guides' in photoshop and 'save for web and devices' options. I just can't seem to find any documentation on it

Comment: Hi Nobby, and welcome to the site. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. Would you be able to provide some more details? What sort of sub-images are you trying to extract from your main image? Once we understand your intentions, it will be easier to give you the right advice.

Comment: I have one big image and I want to have it sliced into 50 smaller images. Think of a big image of a deck of cards and I need all the cards in individual files.

Comment: This has more to do with the "using a photo for some purpose once it's taken" side of things and less with the "actually making the photo" part. Nothing wrong with that, but I've flagged it for a moderator to move it to the Graphic Design stack exchange site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick?

```
convert -crop 100x100 original.jpg tiles_%d.jpg
```

were `100` is the tile size.

Comment: With the right ImageMagic paramaters (and there's lots of them), you can do every sort of slicing you'd need. However, it may not be the right user interface for you.

Comment: Works like a charm. In case you need leading zeroes in your file names (ie. tiles_001.jpg) use `tiles_%03d.jpg` (adjust second number as per your needs).

Answer (score 4):

In Photoshop, pull out guides where you want to slice the image. When you have all the guides in place, choose the slice tool from the tool palette. Once the slice tool is chosen, you will see a button on the toolbar that says "slices from guides". Push that button and Photoshop will put labels on the slices. Then just go through Save For Web dialogue.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to do the same thing for a deck of cards.

Here is the solution I found:

1. Select the "Slice Tool"
2. Right click the image -> "Divide Slices..."