# Split elements from one layer into multiple layers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I have a .psd file with a lot of assets (icons, logos, etc) in a single layer.

Is there any automatic way of splitting these elements into separate layers?

Comment: Hello this question may not contain enough info to help you. No theres no way the computer can know what you want to split off and how. But once you can describe it well  then you have a chance to tell the computer also.

Comment: It is a layer, there are a lot of assets inside of it, and I want to split each asset on its own layer! Hahah

Actually, I've found the answer, will post it here!

Comment: Yes but presumably most icons have several separate elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to slice one image into 50 different images automatically.](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/i-need-to-slice-one-image-into-50-different-images-automatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script did the trick!
Just follow the readme and everything will work :)

https://photoshopscripts.wordpress.com/2012/12/09/split-to-layers/